Constructing Polars DataFrame from different Structs
I’ve parsed multiple Rust structs from a set of JSON data. What is the recommended way of creating a Polars DataFrame from a subset of the fields?
For example, if I parsed the following structs, what's the best way to construct aDataFrame from them both? Should I create multiple series and append each column to its series and then construct using df! macro?
struct Parent {
 name: String
}

struct ChildA {
  parent_name: String,
  my_name: String,
  // some more fields at this level
}

pseudocode:
series_1
series_2
series_3

for data in db {
  append to series_1 for Parent name
  append to series_2 for child name 
  append to series_3 for another field
}
df = df! {
  "parent_name" => series_1,
  "sub_name" => series_2,
  "another_field" => series_3,
};

Is there an easier way? Is this efficient?

I ended up appending values to different Vec and then created a series for each Vec in the DataFrame constructor:
let col1: Vec<String> = vec![];
let col2: Vec<String> = vec![];
let col3: Vec<u8> = vec![];

// later...

let df = DataFrame::new(vec![
  Series::new("col1".into(), col1),
  Series::new("col2".into(), col2),
  Series::new("col3".into(), col3),
])?;



How you parse JSON is up to you, and how you extract the data is also up to you. But Polars provides a way to parse JSON.
https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.JsonReader.html
There is no other simple way. This code is simple enough. The only way to simplify it is to see if Polars' built-in JsonReader can load your data.
    use polars::prelude::*;
    // one json array stored in entire file
    let json_array=r#"
    [
     {  "json_a": 1,         "b": 2,       "c": 3},
     {  "json_a": 21,   "b": 22,    "c": 23},
     {  "json_a": 31,   "b": 32,    "c": 33}
    ]"#;

    //one json object per line;
    let json_lines=r#" 
    {"jsonlines_a": 1,"b": 2,"c": 3}
    {"jsonlines_a": 21,"b": 22,"c": 23}
    {"jsonlines_a": 31,"b": 32,"c": 33}"#;
    let buf=Cursor::new(json_array);
    let df = JsonReader::new(buf).with_json_format(JsonFormat::Json).finish()?;
    let buf1=Cursor::new(json_lines);
    let df1 = JsonReader::new(buf1).with_json_format(JsonFormat::JsonLines).finish()?;

    println!("{}\n{}",df,df1);

At first,We stored data in Vec.
let col1: Vec<String> = vec![];
let col2: Vec<String> = vec![];
let col3: Vec<u8> = vec![];
for data in db {
    col1.push(data.col1);
    col2.push(data.col2);
    col3.push(data.col3);
}
let res = df!{"parent_name"=> col1,
    "sub_name"=> col2,
    "another_field"=> col3
    };

